# Can regular air conditioner be used as heater?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, temperature, efficient-energy-use

In winter season, the normal room temperature is generally 6 to 10 degree Celsius, if the air conditioner is working at 25 degree Celsius will it be working as a heater, making the room warm (relative to surrounding) or it is the fan,  only working without compressor with no change in room temperature (due to air conditioner)

Comment: This is already done, and is known as a heat pump.

Comment: AC sold to china usually have both functions (since heaters are banned in southern china)

Comment: If you simply set a window A/C on the floor in the middle of the room, and switch it on, it will heat the room. The heat that it pumps from its "cold" side (normally faces the room), to its "hot" side (normally hangs out the window) will have no effect because both sides will be immersed in the same body of air (the room), but the quite substantial amount of energy that it uses to pump heat from one side to the other will be "wasted" _as_ heat,... inside the room. Basically, however much electrical energy the A/C unit uses, all of it will end up as heat in the room.

Comment: I feel sure that the OP doesn't want creative ways to use the AC unit or to run it in a heat pump mode. He wants to know if the AC *running as a AC unit* will "heat" the room if the unit is set to "cool" down to $d$ degrees and the room is already $d-5$ degrees. (The answer is no.)

Answer (score 0):

Air conditioners have modes of working, one of them is cooling, the other is reversing the process and then it is heating.

In cooling it removes hot air from the room, in heating it removes heat from outside and bring it to the room

Currently, room air conditioners that have efficient heating  are called "inverters". I still use the  old  machine I bought twenty five years ago, which has a heating cycle, but is less efficient than the modern inverter air conditioners sold nowadays.